# Spring + Hibernate4 + JTA + JBossTS

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jta

I have been struggling for more than 2 days, in order to setup JTA with a stand alone Java application, but unfortunately id didn't work, I would appreciate some help.

**General Information:**

- Spring version: 3.2.3
- Hibernate version: 4.2.3
- Jbossts version:
    4.17.7, I added only the narayana-jta.jar to my classpath.

**Spring configuration file:**

```
<bean class="com.arjuna.ats.jta.TransactionManager" factory-method="transactionManager" id="arjunaTransactionManager" />
<bean class="com.arjuna.ats.jta.UserTransaction" factory-method="userTransaction" id="arjunaUserTransaction" />

<bean class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager" id="transactionManager">
    <property name="transactionManager">
        <ref bean="arjunaTransactionManager" />
    </property>
    <property name="userTransaction">
        <ref bean="arjunaUserTransaction" />
    </property>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven />
```

**Hibernate Configuration File:**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
  "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
  "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=TestDB</property>
        <property name="connection.username">user</property>
        <property name="connection.password">password</property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</property>

        <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
        <property name="current_session_context_class">jta</property>

        <!-- Disable the second-level cache -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <property name="transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JTATransactionFactory</property>
        <property name="transaction.jta.platform">org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossStandAloneJtaPlatform</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

At this point I need to create the hibernate session factory, and I want to create it programmatically, to do so I used the following code snippet, where I create a spring LocalSessionFactoryBean pass to it the hibernate configuration resource and retrieve the SessionFactory from it using the .getObject() method.

This code works correctly and creates a SessionFactory object, this object is used in the next code snippet.

```
LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
JtaTransactionManager trxManager = applicationContext.getBean(JtaTransactionManager.class);
sessionFactoryBean.setJtaTransactionManager(trxManager);
sessionFactoryBean.setConfigLocation(resource);
sessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
SessionFactory sessionFactory = sessionFactoryBean.getObject();
```

After that I have a Service class that does an insert into a TABLE:

```
package com.core.service;

import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class TestService {

    @Transactional
    public void testTrx() throws Exception {
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = // retrieve session factory created before

        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Query query = session.createSQLQuery("insert into TABLE1 (col1, col2) values (:v1, :v2)");
        query.setParameter("v1", "value1");
        query.setParameter("v2", "value2");

        query.executeUpdate();
    }
}
```

And finally a JUnit test that loads the Spring context and initializes everything, and then executes the following lines:

```
@Test
public void testTransactionRollback() throws Exception {
    TestService testService = applicationContext.getBean(TestService.class);
    testService.testTrx();
}
```

**The Problem:** When I execute the JUnit test I get a green bar and I see that there is an SQL statement that inserts into the table, and I see that a transaction is opened and committed, however if I go to the database I don't see the inserted rows.

**My Conclusion:** I tried to set the hibernate configuration **connection.autocommit=true** and the row is created in the database correctly, so I assume that Yes JTA transactions are opened and closed but the Hibernate Session Factory is not using them, instead it is using its own. Am I missing some configuration?

```
15:14:20.423 [main]            DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'testService'
15:14:20.425 [main]            DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'transactionManager'
15:14:20.432 [main]            DEBUG o.s.t.jta.JtaTransactionManager - Creating new transaction with name [com.core.service.TestService.testTrx]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''
15:14:20.448 [main]            INFO  com.arjuna.ats.arjuna - ARJUNA012163: Starting service com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.recovery.ActionStatusService on port 36097
15:14:20.453 [main]            INFO  com.arjuna.ats.arjuna - ARJUNA012337: TransactionStatusManagerItem host: 127.0.0.1 port: 36097
15:14:20.460 [main]            INFO  com.arjuna.ats.arjuna - ARJUNA012170: TransactionStatusManager started on port 36097 and host 127.0.0.1 with service com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.recovery.ActionStatusService
15:14:20.488 [main]            DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'sessionFactoryManagerImpl'
15:14:20.524 [main]            DEBUG o.h.e.j.i.LogicalConnectionImpl - Connection provider reports to not support aggressive release; overriding
15:14:20.533 [main]            DEBUG o.h.e.t.i.TransactionCoordinatorImpl - successfully registered Synchronization
15:14:20.565 [main]            DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - insert into TABLE1 (col1, col2) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into TABLE1 (col1, col2) values (?, ?)
15:14:20.566 [main]            DEBUG o.h.e.j.i.LogicalConnectionImpl - Obtaining JDBC connection
15:14:20.566 [main]            DEBUG o.h.e.j.i.LogicalConnectionImpl - Obtained JDBC connection
15:14:20.575 [main]            DEBUG o.h.e.q.spi.NativeSQLQueryPlan - bindNamedParameters() value1 -> v1 [1]
15:14:20.582 [main]            DEBUG o.h.e.q.spi.NativeSQLQueryPlan - bindNamedParameters() value2 -> v2 [2]
15:14:20.589 [main]            DEBUG o.s.t.jta.JtaTransactionManager - Initiating transaction commit
15:14:20.590 [main]            DEBUG o.h.e.j.i.LogicalConnectionImpl - Aggressively releasing JDBC connection
15:14:20.590 [main]            DEBUG o.h.e.j.i.LogicalConnectionImpl - Releasing JDBC connection
15:14:20.590 [main]            DEBUG o.h.e.j.i.LogicalConnectionImpl - Released JDBC connection
15:14:20.595 [Listener:36097]  DEBUG com.arjuna.ats.arjuna - Recovery listener existing com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.recovery.ActionStatusService
```

Comment: Why do you want to programmatically create a SessionFactory bean?! This really should be in XML, next to that you shouldn't really be operating/working with the `ApplicationContext` directly. In your configuration I nowhere see a `<tx:annotation-driven ../>` which basically makes your service work without transactions. Is it possible to see the whole project (maybe on github or as a zip).

Comment: @M.Deinum you are right I missed the <tx:annotation-driven /> by mistake, the creation of the SessionFactory programmatically because database connection parameters can be loaded at runtime and not design time, I know that it is not recommended to use the ApplicationContext directly but this is my current situation and it cannot be changed. The source code displayed is an abstraction from the source code not the real code.

Comment: Specify the parameters in a properties file and use a PropertyPlaceholder to configure the datasource. Also make sure that the component is in the same context as the tx:annotation-driven.

Comment: I have only one ApplicationContext. are you suggesting to switch the hibernate configurations from an XML file to a properties file?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because Your database connection is not bound with JTA. You have only synchronized hibernate with JTA.
You should use com.arjuna.ats.jdbc.TransactionalDriver in order to create conenction:

```
TransactionalDriver arjunaJDBC2Driver = new TransactionalDriver();
Connection connection = arjunaJDBC2Driver.connect(url, dbProps);
```

spring example:

```
 <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
  <property name="driverClassName">
   <value>com.arjuna.ats.jdbc.TransactionalDriver</value>
  </property>
  <property name="url" value="jdbc:arjuna:mysql://host:3306/dbName"/>
  <property name="connectionProperties">
    <ref bean="dsProps"/>
  </property>
 </bean>
```

Hope this help